# How do the agents communicate with each other in the Mission: Impossible films?

Tags: mission-impossible, mission-impossible-fallout

In the Mission: Impossible films, the IMF agents are always able to talk to each other from far away. Occasionally they touch their ears, indicating that they're probably using some kind of ear piece... but we can never quite see it, can we? Why not? Is it some kind of implant that's deep inside their ear?

Comment: [The earpieces used for communication are the most realistic devices added to Mission: Impossible, mostly because they are actually used by military and Secret Service. ... Now, the devices consist of small microphones and earpieces. Technically, we don’t know if Agent Hunt’s team uses throat-mounted microphones like the military; they could be hiding equipment beneath turtlenecks or button down shirts.](http://wethenerdy.com/how-realistic-are-the-gadgets-in-mission-impossible/)